# icefaces menupopup strange problem

Tags: html, icefaces

I have this piece of code:

```
<ice:panelGroup menuPopup="menuPopup1" onclick="fireContextMenu(this, event);">
        <img src="/resources/images/external/bg-suppliers.gif"> </img>
    </ice:panelGroup>
```

it renders this HTML as output (as expected):

```
 <div class="icePnlGrp" id="j_id62" onclick="fireContextMenu(this, event);">
      <img src="/resources/images/external/bg-suppliers.gif">
    </div>
```

If i simply add a **menuPopup** attribute to the ice:panelGroup like:

```
<ice:panelGroup menuPopup="menuPopup1" onclick="fireContextMenu(this, event);">
        <img src="/resources/images/external/bg-suppliers.gif"> </img>
    </ice:panelGroup>
```

it simply CLOSES the divs before img tag:

```
<div class="icePnlGrp" id="j_id62" onclick="fireContextMenu(this, event);"></div>
 <img src="/resources/images/external/bg-suppliers.gif">
```

which is really strange...

Do you guys have a work-around? It's probably a bug from icefaces but I cannot find anything related to this on their site...

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution found.

Working with different templates I had two ice:forms in the final page and two body as well, and my panelGroup from one form referenced the menuPopup from the other form which gave the above issue.